# How to push elements of a 1d array into a 9x9 array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Having trouble inserting values of a array into a 9x9 multidimensional array for my sudoku solver in javascript.

```
var sudoku = Array(9).fill(null).map( ()=>Array(9).fill(null) ); // creates an empty 9x9 array

var problemString = "1-58-2----9--764-52--4--819-19--73-6762-83-9-----61-5---76---3-43--2-5-16--3-89--"; //sample sudoku problem in string format
var problemArray = problemString.split(''); // turns the problem string into an array


for(i=0; i<problemArray.length; i++){
    for(j=0; j<problemArray.lenght; j++){
        sudoku[i][j]=(problemArray[i]); 
    }
}

console.log(sudoku); 

/*[ [ null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null ],
    [ null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null ],
    [ null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null ],
    [ null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null ],
    [ null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null ],
    [ null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null ],
    [ null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null ],
    [ null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null ],
    [ null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null ] ]*/
```

Comment: you misspelled `length` as `lenght` in your inner loop. A good Code Editor like Visual Studio Code can help you by highlighting such errors.

Comment: Thanks. Will do.

Comment: Just curious, why are you using `split('')` (then looping through its result) over by simply looping over your problem string when converting your string to a 9x9 array?